# R language: Maximize function subject to another function

Tags: r, optimization

I am interested to know how can I maximize a function `f(x) = xy` subject to `x + y = 100` using R. I know a couple of packages like optim or optimize that helps to do it but it requires a vector of values for the parameters to be optimized over. I would like to know if I could do it without the use of the values.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: Isn't this just a limit approaching infinity? Infinity being hit with `x=100` or `100/(100-100)`

Comment: I am sorry. My bad. it is xy rather than x/y

Comment: that doesn't change too much, you can still express `y` in terms of `x` and feed that function to `optimise` - i.e. `function(x) 100*x - x^2`. For this hypothetical example, you know that `x` has to lie between 0 and 100, so I don't know why needing to specify an upper and lower bound is that much of a problem.

Comment: This looks like a familiar problem from economics homework. You can look up cobb-douglas functions (which xy is a special case of) to find out how this can be solved analytically. Once you know how to do it, you should be able to solve this in your head... :)

Comment: Aren't you just maximizing `x*(100-x)`? Seems like freshman calculus. How is this an R problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I was able to do it.

```
maxiFunc <- function(x) {
    x1 <- x[1]
    y = (500-x1)/2
    x1*y
}
xmax = optimize(maxiFunc, interval= c(0, 500), tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, maximum = TRUE)
paste("The maximum value of the function is", xmax$objective)
```

I didn't mean to ask a high school calculus question but to know if there is a way to solve the question where I don't specify the `interval= c(0, 500)`. Thanks for the inputs.